# Why do SQL joins fail in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I just try **simple** joins with C# using oracle db. Should be no big deal. But it **ALWAYS** fails. It works in MS-Access. Where is the problem ? *(OleDb or Odbc makes no difference here, I tried both)*

**Edit:**

- Might Oracle version be the problem ? (seems we are using 8.1.7.0.0 and 8.1.5.0.0 modules)

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string n = Environment.NewLine + "--------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

            // connect
            string connectionString = "dsn=TEST;uid=read;pwd=myPwd";
            OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            // select (key is actually text not numeral)
            string query = "select * from INFOR.ZEITEN where (KEY = 0)";
            query = "select a.KEY, b.GREG from INFOR.ZEITEN a inner join INFOR.ZEITEN b on (a.AUSWEIS = b.AUSWEIS) where (a.KEY like '1')";

            try
            {
                query = query.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
                Console.WriteLine(n + query);
                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, connection);
                OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); // throws exception
                if (reader != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(n + "success, now read with reader!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n + e.Message + n + e.StackTrace);
            }

            // wait
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

*And the successful, simple select:*

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem related to C# at all. If one of the two SQL statements fails, you should check whether it is valid. Have you tried to execute the statement with a query tool?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, I know. You tell that to the SO users that flamed on my Q yesterday when I asked _why it fails in oracle_! They wanted to see C# code.

Comment: What driver version are you using, and what database version are you connecting to? It's possible one of those is too old to support `join` syntax. That seems unlikely, but we still seem to be getting questions about 8i so who knows. (And you can still set `dbms=v8` in Pro*C which has this effect too).

Comment: @AlexPoole `8.1.7.0.0` read my edit above.

Comment: @mini-me - well there's your problem then *8-) ANSI joins weren't supported by Oracle until 9i, as Joe has said. You will have to use the older syntax with a list of tables separated by commas and all the join conditions in the `where` clause. Or you could move to a supported version, of course...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ANSI joins (ex. `inner join`) were first supported in 9i.  You will need to use the old syntax:

```
select a.KEY, b.GREG 
 from INFOR.ZEITEN a,
      INFOR.ZEITEN b 
where (a.AUSWEIS = b.AUSWEIS) 
      and  (a.KEY like '1')
```

Note that the `like` operator is equivalent to `=` in this case, but you probably know that

Comment: This seems to be right. My join queries that failed before work now when I change the syntax like you suggest. Can I use all kinds of joins with the old syntax ? Or are there some limitations ?

Comment: Left/Right outer joins are supported with `(+)`, but Full Outer Joins are not supported.  Here's some info: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6585774577187

Answer (score 1):

The word `key` is a reserved word.  That means that it is a very poor choice for an identity.  You need to escape it with a double quote.  This might work:

```
        query = "select a.\"KEY\", b.GREG
                 from INFOR.ZEITEN a inner join
                      INFOR.ZEITEN b
                      on (a.AUSWEIS = b.AUSWEIS)
                 where (a.\"KEY\" like '1')";
```

I am guessing the `\"` will work in this context, but there might be another method to insert this character.

Comment: will like '1' be valid?

Comment: If that were the case, shouldn't the second statement fail, too?

Comment: @JeffRosenberg . . . They should both fail.  `KEY` *really is* a reserved word in SQL.  This is curious.  Here is a simple example:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6010c/3.

Comment: It didn't work for me without quotes. It failed as expected. But it appears to be working for the OP, based on his screenshots, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan . . . I guess I learned something.  Still, it is a bad idea to use reserved words for identifiers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Absolutely agree. But why the fiddle behave in that manner? I am confused. And how the second example works?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan . . . I learned that Oracle is better about using context for disambiguating reserved words.  Clearly, context matters.  I don't know why one query fails and the other succeeds.

Comment: `key` is a keyword but not a reserved word in Oracle: docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think the `KEY` is numeric then you can't use `LIKE`. It is because the `WHERE KEY = 0` works fine.

Comment: `KEY` is text. I created that table myself for testing and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

What's the error?  Could you edit your question and add the actual error the system's throwing at you? 
Firstly, I would personally recommend using the ODP .NET (Oracle Data provider for .NET). You can download the latest version for Oracle 12c [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html). Or look it up for the version you need.
ODBC is a very old driver written in C and works using the native Windows RPC technique.
For full .NET support you're better off with ODP .NET.
Secondly, check if you have any constraints on the tables that's causing the sql to fail.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; most, if not all, should be a comment.

Comment: @AlexPoole I think this passes as an answer. As I understand there is the option to use an extra package that might help me to avoid the version problem I'm having ... ? Actually I'm not willing to use extra packages / drivers. This adds more dependencies. Since I have the solving option to go old syntax.